# Execute function focusIn component (viewstack)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a viewstack with 2 component
1. Start
2. Config

When you press a button the selectedIndex changes to 1 - so you go to the 'Config' component. In that component I'm trying to execute a function after the component is shown.

I tried to use creationComplete and focusIn but both functions execute the function right when the application itself is started.

Can anyone help me out please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried listening to the [ViewStack's change event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/ViewStack.html#event%3achange)?  If `configComponent` was your component, then you could check whether that component is the one to be shown as follows:

```
private function handleViewChange(e:IndexChangedEvent):void {

  if (e.relatedObject === configComponent) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```